Sex rokna in bharamcharya
Bharamcharya ka palan krte huye yadi virya khud nikl jaye to kya Bharamcharya tut jata h

I’m voting to close this question because please read forum rules on language

I’m voting to close this question because 1) it asks for personal advice & 2) it isn't in English
